# libcurl implementation on public-private key authentication on SSH

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

- Created public and private key

  1. ssh-keygen -t rsa <-- performed the operation in the SSH client
  2. ssh-copy-id @
     Note: no passphrase on the creation of the key

**Can someone please help me on how to implement libcurl PutFile method using 
- username
- private key
- public key
- sftp**

Tried to browse on libcurl examples, but sadly this is the most similar example https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/usercertinmem.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about usercertinmem.c, just take [fileupload.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html) and add SSH options as needed.

Something like this:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://username@host/path/file");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_size);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_PUBLICKEY);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, pubkey_filename);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, privkey_filename);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5, known_host_sign);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

You can read about these SSH-specific and other options in the [options documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/easy_setopt_options.html).

Instead of [`CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5.html) you can also use [`CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS.html) or [`CURLOPT_SSH_KEYFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSH_KEYFUNCTION.html).

Comment: I'll try this one, and will give a feedback. Thanks for this input. Appreciate it RustyX.

Comment: curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5, known_host_sign); <-- will it be okay if this line will not be present?

Comment: That's okay for testing, but in production you should check that the server's key has not changed. Otherwise you're susceptible to a MITM attack.